# Killed app notification click intent putExtra method not working

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, push-notification

I have a problem `intent.putExtra` is not working when the app is killed. Wake up and running mode all works. I use firebase messaging service, `getData()` method, pending intent.

```
private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(int newsID) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailedNewsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("newsID", newsID);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
    // All the parents of SecondActivity will be added to task stack.
    stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);

    //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(100, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return pendingIntent;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: I send notification using FirebaseMessagingService, messageEvent.getData() method. All notifications are allowed, set onclick pending intent to start activity.

Comment: Is your activity is launcher activity which open on pending intent?

Comment: not is child activity

Comment: you have to pass intent to splash or launcher activity then you need to navigate. 
Because when the app is running it was working fine but after killing the app, Pending intent will get in launcher activity. Try it once.

Comment: Can you show your code  and also notification `Json`

Comment: i share code pending intent please help me replace launcher activity

Comment: @NovruzCeferov do you have `notification` field in Notification Json?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your onMessageReceived() function is not getting triggered. There are two types of notifications from firebase data messages and other one is notification message. Currently you are getting notification message which doesn't invoke onMessageReceived() in killed state. Use "data" messages instead.This could be done by the back end developer.Please ask him to send data messages.
Notification messages trigger onMessageRecieved() only when app is in foreground but data message invoke onMessageRecieved() in both foreground and background state

Please replace "notification" key from payload to "data" key.
 Please refer to this link [Click](https://wajahatkarim.com/2018/05/firebase-notifications-in-background--foreground-in-android/) for more information

Comment: i use data messages

Answer (score 0):

Check that data first then use that

```
// Check if message contains a data payload.
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
   try {
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"data\":"+remoteMessage.getData().toString()+"}");
      //decode your json data and use that
    } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

// Check if message contains a notification payload.
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
    String stingMessage = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    //show the message string as notification or as your want
}
```

To show notification and add pending intent

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(this, YourActivityWantToL.class);
    myintent.putExtra("message", stingMessage);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(TAG)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle() .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(stingMessage);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

but if you are targeting and running app on 26 or higher you have to use notification channel

Comment: All notifications are allowed not problem this data method