# Can not get value from notification when user click on notification while app is closed

Tags: android

how can I pass data like order_id in intent when the application is killed or closed???

My application working properly when the application is in the foreground or background. I can get value from intent (order_id).

I'm also able to open a specific activity when the application is closed by using click_action.

I'm having a problem with when the application when it is closed. I can't get order_id from notification's intent when the application is closed.

```
MyFirebaseMessagingService.java
private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody, Intent intent) {

     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
     MyOrderDetailActivity.class);
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
     bundle.putString("id", "Android");
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 ..............}



    OrderDetailActivity.java
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
    {
super.onNewIntent(intent);
         setIntent(intent);
         Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
         Log.e(TAG, "onNewIntent: " + bundle.getString("id"));

    }


AndroidManifest.xml

<activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MyOrderDetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.vonpharmacy.ui.activities.MyOrderDetailActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>
```

still, I'm getting null value, I want to get the id in OrderDetailActivity.java so I can get the detail and show order information.

Comment: You get notification when app is close ?

Comment: yes, I can get a notification when the app is closed @Ali

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59764458/8059396 ... It could be helpful

Comment: Can you share that php firebase payload message which you used.

Comment: $data = array(
           "title" => $title,
           "text" => $notification,
           "customer_id" => $customer_id,
           "order_id" => $order_id,
           "type" => $type,           
           "click_action" => "com.vonpharmacy.ui.activities.NotificationTestActivity",
       );

Comment: $notification = array(
           'title' => $title,
           "body" => $notification,
           "content_available" => true, // only IOS
           "sound" => "default",
           "click_action" => "com.vonpharmacy.ui.activities.NotificationTestActivity",
           "tag" => $order_id,
       );

Answer (score 2):

You need to get `data message` for that purpose. By default if you send notification message in FCM then if the app is in background then the notification is shown by FCM itself and receiver is not called.

For data message it is called every time, whether the app is in foreground or background.

[Read more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Comment: no, I'm not having an issue with showing data in the notification tray. I can not get value from intent when the application is closed.

Comment: data message is a different kind of notification, you can set `order_id` with your notification, so you can pass it in `intent`, please read the link mentioned and read it carefully

Comment: @SavanPatel Yes. I understand. By default if it is a notification message then notification is shown by FCM itself, your code of showing notification is not working. It will always take you to the Splash screen of the app.

Comment: @ Rahul Gaur, You are right so how can I solve this.

Comment: @ Rahul Gaur I'm using  click_action so it will open my order detail page directly from the notification.

Comment: @SavanPatel Dude, same reply. Your sendNotification or whatever won't be called if you have Notification message and App is in background/killed. You need Data message. Please read carefully about the same.

Answer (score 0):

**If you send notification directly from fcm console ,you cant get value from notification when app is closed.You use server, which helps you to send notification.Define only data,You cant define notification inside payload.
For example;**

payload = {

```
priority: "high",
content_available: true,
data:{
   type: 'type',
   id: id,

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I used the below way to **firebase notifications**. Especially when messages were sent from firebase console and my application was not able to call **onMessageReceived** method if the application was closed or in background.

The behavior of receiving the notifications is different (if the application is in the background or in foreground) Or say Closed or used by users.

The method below or service will only be called If the application is in the foreground, In other words, you can get the values from the intent.

```
public class PushNotificationMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage message){
    }
}
```

If your application is closed. In this case, your application will receive notifications and display them in the system tray. You have to click on the notification, you will receive the data in the **onNewIntent** method of your activity.

Comment: Call the method "onNewIntent(getIntent());" from your onCreate method of activity

Comment: and let me know, if it's help

Answer (score 0):

You can't receive any message **onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage message)**,if you directly send notification from firebase. You need to create a web service usinng php, java, python etc which hosted on any cluod or sharedhost . If you have not web service then you can use firebase cloud function or typescritp which is free to use.

Firebase notification has two type services 
**one is notification 
and another is only data**.
if you directly send notification from firebase then only send **notification** to application .In these case app is running then not any issue but app in background can't handle manually. So notification handle on background and running mode if only send **data**.And only data can send possible by third party server.

Answer (score 0):

try it;

$data = array((

```
    'data' => array("title" => $title, "text" => $notification, "customer_id" => $customer_id, "order_id" => $order_id, "type" => $type, "click_action" => "com.vonpharmacy.ui.activities.NotificationTestActivity"),//use this only

  //don't use this line//  'notification' => array("title" => $title, "text" => $notification, "customer_id" => $customer_id, "order_id" => $order_id, "type" => $type, "click_action" => "com.vonpharmacy.ui.activities.NotificationTestActivity")//don't use it, this is only for your knowledge .If use it get same problem before you got.
```

);

I hope this helps you.